# jinja2 whitespace control in block and around block

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to output a 2 line block that should:

- Not have whitespace before the block
- Not have whitespace after the block
- Have a newline for each item in the block

Like this:

```
apple
pear
```

However, depending on how I use whitespace-control, I can't find the necessary configuration.

My closest is:

```
{% for fruit in fruits -%}
{{ fruit }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which renders:

```
apple
pear
<newline>
```

Other attempts render blocks as follows:

```
<newline>
apple
pear
```

or

```
applepear
```

I just can't get

```
apple
pear
```

I would appreciate any available assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you...

```
{% for fruit in fruits -%}
{{ fruit }}
{% endfor -%}
```

and now?

Comment: That removes the newline after {{ fruit }}

Comment: I've already tested the various combinations, as explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is actually an issue with my IDE, which is adding the newline at EOF in the editor.

When I view the file in a shell, there is no newline.

So the following template format does actually work:

```
{% for fruit in fruits -%}
{{ fruit }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `Okay...!`   